# Having problems with calling the original buffered image

Tags: java, opencv, jlabel, jdialog, javacv

I have some problems here. Now what I'm try to do is:

1. Load an Image,
2. Select a process or a filter,
3. Generate.

I dont have problems with the 3 steps but then I wanted to preserve the loaded image in my second Jlabel whenever the selected ItemList is Process and then proceed again with generating processed image.

Now what this program does is it generates the desired filter but the when I will apply another filter the image that will get filtered is the previous one that is already filtered and not the actual loaded image.

```
private void btnLoadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG File", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp");
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);
    int choice = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        load = cvLoadImage(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        if (load != null)
            src.setIcon(new ImageIcon(load.getBufferedImage()));
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to load image.");
    }
}
```

//THis method is for when you click the generate button to add filter to the image.

```
private void genActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

       if(cbo.getSelectedItem().equals("Process..")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose a filter");
          } else if(cbo.getSelectedItem().equals("Grayscale")){
        if(load != load){
            fx = toGray(load);
            dst.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fx.getBufferedImage()));
          } else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No image loaded.");
          }
     }
```

//This is for the toGray method

```
public static IplImage toGray(IplImage load){                          
    IplImage toGray = null;
    double r, g, b, gray;
    CvMat mtx = CvMat.createHeader(load.height(), load.width(), CV_32FC1);
    cvGetMat(load, mtx, null, 0);
    CvScalar rgb, scalar;
        for(int i = 0; i < ((mtx.rows())-1); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < (mtx.cols()-1); j++){
                rgb = cvGet2D(mtx, i, j);
                r = rgb.getVal(0);
                g = rgb.getVal(1);
                b = rgb.getVal(2);
                gray = (r+b+g)/3;
                    scalar = new CvScalar(gray, gray, gray, 0);
                    cvSet2D(mtx, i, j, scalar);
                }
}
 toGray = mtx.asIplImage();
 return toGray;  
}
```

//I know there is already OpenCV functions for this.. but we are required to do this pixel by pixel so please bear me. XD

Comment: I'd suggest putting a bit more code. From what you have shown the first thing that strikes me is the "if(load==load)", it's the same as putting in "if(true)" if they are not different variables (one a class variable and another an argument passed to the method, which I doubt).

Comment: what does getBufferedImage do?
In c++ OpenCV you would have to call a .copyTo(Mat) there, otherwise you would work on the buffered image's data (and the next one who wants to access the buffered image will get the modified/filtered buffered image)

Comment: Hey Joy thanks, I've change it to load != null already for the hint.
@Micka, Yeah.. That's exactly what my program does if you use the loaded image and filter it once the filtered image is now being used if you filter it with different process. How could I be able to stick to my loaded image when processing different filter with the image?

Comment: @ECE179Stud in your toGray method instead of `CvMat mtx = CvMat.createHeader(load.height(), load.width(), CV_32FC1);` try `CvMat mtx = load.clone()` this should copy the image instead of using the same data array

Comment: @Micka, yeah i think so.. but for now we're not allowed to use that so i kinda use that thing..